I am integrated Pingfederate with sharepoint server using WS Federation I'm getting this error?
When I'm trying to access the SharePoint site it will showing this error. "Sorry, this site hasn't been shared with you."
Trusted identity provider is also added to the SharePoint server
doing this with the authentication policy.
